# USB booting without amnesia

Tags: boot

Is it possible to remove booted USB stick and save all changes what has made while i was working with OS on USB stick?
Definitely, don't get amnesia after removing USB drive.

Comment: Is that a trick question? If you remove the USB stick how do you expect to save anything on it later?

Comment: I thnk you mean a USB with pesistence. What OS is on your USB?

Answer (score 1):

Either a persistent live USB stick or a live system running in RAM using the boot option `toram`. Both are possible.

- A persistent live drive must be plugged in while the system is working, and the modifications will survive shutdown and reboot.
- Running in RAM will continue also when the drive is unplugged, but the modifications will not survive shutdown and reboot.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1440168/264083 and https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/create-persistent-storage-live-usb-with.html for specific solutions.